# Search Controller - Problems using NSPredicate with model

Tags: swift, nspredicate, uisearchcontroller

I have a table view which get the json data from my server. 
Now I want to add a search bar using `SearchContoller`. The cells (custom) are correctly displayed before the search:

[image]

but when I start typing nothing is shown. Here is the code:

MODEL

```
import Foundation
class PreviousLocations:NSObject{

 let locationId: String?
 let locationName: String?
 let locationCity:String?
 let locationCountry:String?
 let locationLatitude:String?
 let locationLongitude:String?
 let sport:String?


  init(dictionary:NSDictionary) {
    locationId = dictionary["locationId"]    as? String
    locationName = dictionary["locationName"]    as? String
    locationCity = dictionary["locationCity"]    as? String
    locationCountry = dictionary["locationCountry"]    as? String
    sport = dictionary["sport"]    as? String
    locationLatitude = dictionary["locationLatitude"]    as? String
    locationLongitude = dictionary["locationLongitude"]    as? String

   }
}
```

Then in PreviousLocationsViewControllors

```
 var previousLocation = [PreviousLocations]()
 var filteredPreviousLocations  = [PreviousLocations]()

 fun tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  
          if section == 0 {     
              return 1
          }

          if section == 1{

              if (self.searchController.active) {
                 return filteredPreviousLocations.count     
              }else{

                 return previousLocation.count
              }

        }
        return 1
    }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
 }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

       if indexPath.section == 0{

        let addLocationCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addLocationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        addLocationCell.textLabel?.text = "Add Location"
        return addLocationCell

    }else{

    var locCells:PreviousLocationsTableCell
    let locations : PreviousLocations

        if (self.searchController.active) {

        locCells =  self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("previousLocationCell") as! PreviousLocationsTableCell

            locations = filteredPreviousLocations[indexPath.row]
            locCells.useLocations(locations)

         }else{

           locCells = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("previousLocationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PreviousLocationsTableCell


            locations = previousLocation[indexPath.row]
            locCells.useLocations(locations)

    }

    return locCells
    }
}


//MARK: - Search


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{

    filteredPreviousLocations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.locationName == %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array  = (previousLocation as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    print(array)
    filteredPreviousLocations = array as! Array
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and the custom Cell

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


class PreviousLocationsTableCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var conteningView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var locatioNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationCityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sportImage: UIImageView!


func useLocations(location:PreviousLocations) {



    conteningView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    conteningView.exclusiveTouch = false
    // Fill in the data
    locatioNameLabel.text = location.locationName
    locationCityLabel.text = location.locationCity

    let imageSport = UIImage(named: "\(location.sport!).png")
    sportImage.image = imageSport

    func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


 }

  }
```

If I try do change this

```
    `filteredPreviousLocations = array as! Array`
```

into this

```
    `filteredPreviousLocations = array as! [String]`
```

as explained in this in [This](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift) tutorial, I get the error
 `Cannot assign a value of type '[String]' to a value of type '[PreviousLocations]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types of the properties are clearly defined as `[PreviousLocations]`, so you don't need to cast the types except in the filter line. The format string is supposed to be `locationName == %@`.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
  let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "locationName == %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
  filteredPreviousLocations = (previousLocation as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Alternatively you can filter with Swift's `filter` function.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
  filteredPreviousLocations = previousLocation.filter { $0.locationName == searchController.searchBar.text!}
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

As in both functions the array `filteredPreviousLocations` is set distinctly, calling `removeAll` is not needed, too

Edit: to get search results before typed the complete name you should filter for a partial string rather than the whole location name

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
  filteredPreviousLocations = previousLocation.filter { $0.locationName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text!, options: [.AnchoredSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch, .DiacriticInsensitiveSearch]) != nil}
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @ In the first solution I get ` Value of type '[PreviousLocations]' has no member 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'` and in the second I stil get an empty table when I start typing

Comment: thanks but now ` Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[PreviousLocations]'` In the tutorial the filtered array is declared as `var filteredTableData = [String]()` but if I do that then I cannot  do this ` locations = filteredPreviousLocations[indexPath.row]
            locCells.useLocations(locations)`

Comment: after your last edit I get `Value of type 'PreviousLocations' has no member 'locationNamerangeOfString'`

Comment: I missed a dot before `rangeOfString`. The filtered array must have the same type as the main array